# How to correct error related to inline expression Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, inline

I am dealing with the next issue, I can not understand what is the problem with it:

I have the next object (tablas_pais(1)) is the following object:

```
  list(structure(list(att = c(-9.3913415429545, -1.14919783479245
  ), se = c(4.11439919716143, 2.23875493079654), conf.low = c(-17.4555639693909, 
 -5.53715749915367), conf.high = c(-1.32711911651809, 3.23876182956877
 ), Gender = c("Male", "Female")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"), 
 structure(list(event.time = c(-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 
 4), estimate = c(-8.98971405222411, 6.29264679607431, 7.62870519569896, 
 -10.055928764989, -12.387440503361, -14.7729948201452, -11.9849275794849, 
 9.73853656774817, -17.5498813795296), std.error = c(21.978184419797, 
 8.05786330398263, 8.43933472441565, 5.84534116964665, 5.04672698651591, 
 4.07359931451878, 6.61481847783054, 8.60701186588496, 7.15049797997214
 ), conf.low = c(-65.0090578736049, -14.2457291802821, -13.8819885231557, 
 -24.9548926867201, -25.2508476361002, -25.1560344849236, 
 -28.8451824371077, -12.1995429287277, -35.7755089920331), 
    conf.high = c(47.0296297691567, 26.8310227724307, 29.1393989145537, 
    4.84303515674203, 0.475966629378284, -4.38995515536671, 
    4.87532727813782, 31.676616064224, 0.675746232973953)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
 c(NA, 
 -9L)), structure(list(event.time = c(-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 
 2, 3, 4), estimate = c(-7.33231459016049, 10.9927938757472, 
 3.35045506708216, -2.12169328409651, -1.67443813617147, -0.271789255812684, 
 -3.38170817525763, 0.160143460539644, -0.578197067260109), 
    std.error = c(6.76176620720626, 3.88397714343596, 4.43020566027858, 
    3.41224748723083, 2.37708161448678, 2.726625370482, 3.09581643195207, 
    2.36911356255524, 3.79701837351542), conf.low = c(-24.5868213403075, 
    1.08175764864265, -7.95443349714388, -10.8289815128509, 
    -7.74021584955956, -7.22952402782603, -11.2815355111103, 
    -5.88530157620375, -10.2673340691327), conf.high = c(9.92219215998651, 
    20.9038301028517, 14.6553436313082, 6.58559494465791, 
    4.39133957721662, 6.68594551620066, 4.51811916059507, 
    6.20558849728303, 9.1109399346125)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -9L)), structure(list(data = structure(list(type = c("dynamic", 
 "dynamic", "dynamic", "dynamic", "dynamic", "dynamic", "dynamic", 
 "dynamic", "dynamic", "dynamic", "dynamic", "dynamic", "dynamic", 
 "dynamic", "dynamic", "dynamic", "dynamic", "dynamic"), term = c("ATT(-4)", 
 "ATT(-3)", "ATT(-2)", "ATT(-1)", "ATT(0)", "ATT(1)", "ATT(2)", 
 "ATT(3)", "ATT(4)", "ATT(-4)", "ATT(-3)", "ATT(-2)", "ATT(-1)", 
 "ATT(0)", "ATT(1)", "ATT(2)", "ATT(3)", "ATT(4)"), event.time = c(-4, 
 -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4), 
     estimate = c(-8.98971405222411, 6.29264679607431, 7.62870519569896, 
    -10.055928764989, -12.387440503361, -14.7729948201452, 
    -11.9849275794849, 9.73853656774817, -17.5498813795296, 
    -7.33231459016049, 10.9927938757472, 3.35045506708216, 
    -2.12169328409651, -1.67443813617147, -0.271789255812684, 
    -3.38170817525763, 0.160143460539644, -0.578197067260109
    ), std.error = c(21.978184419797, 8.05786330398263, 8.43933472441565, 
    5.84534116964665, 5.04672698651591, 4.07359931451878, 
    6.61481847783054, 8.60701186588496, 7.15049797997214, 
    6.76176620720626, 3.88397714343596, 4.43020566027858, 
    3.41224748723083, 2.37708161448678, 2.726625370482, 3.09581643195207, 
    2.36911356255524, 3.79701837351542), conf.low = c(-65.0090578736049, 
    -14.2457291802821, -13.8819885231557, -24.9548926867201, 
    -25.2508476361002, -25.1560344849236, -28.8451824371077, 
    -12.1995429287277, -35.7755089920331, -24.5868213403075, 
    1.08175764864265, -7.95443349714388, -10.8289815128509, 
    -7.74021584955956, -7.22952402782603, -11.2815355111103, 
    -5.88530157620375, -10.2673340691327), conf.high = c(47.0296297691567, 
    26.8310227724307, 29.1393989145537, 4.84303515674203, 
    0.475966629378284, -4.38995515536671, 4.87532727813782, 
    31.676616064224, 0.675746232973953, 9.92219215998651, 
    20.9038301028517, 14.6553436313082, 6.58559494465791, 
    4.39133957721662, 6.68594551620066, 4.51811916059507, 
    6.20558849728303, 9.1109399346125), point.conf.low = c(-52.0661639606056, 
    -9.50047507207857, -8.91208691763397, -21.5125869348457, 
    -22.2788436367385, -22.757102764049, -24.9497335603028, 
    -7.13089670389524, -31.5645998918014, -20.5851328281648, 
    3.38033855783594, -5.33258847116934, -8.80957546540624, 
    -6.33343248887788, -5.61587678129059, -9.44939688463099, 
    -4.48323379735401, -8.02021632798719), point.conf.high = c(34.0867358561574, 
    22.0857686642272, 24.1694973090319, 1.40072940486763, 
    -2.49603736998342, -6.78888687624131, 0.97987840133298, 
    26.6079698393916, -3.53516286725779, 5.92050364784378, 
    18.6052491936584, 12.0334986053337, 4.56618889721322, 
    2.98455621653494, 5.07229826966522, 2.68598053411573, 
    4.8035207184333, 6.86382219346697), gender = c("Male", 
    "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
    "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
    "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female"), prepost = c("pre", 
    "pre", "pre", "pre", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
    "post", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "post", "post", "post", 
    "post", "post")), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame"), 
    layers = list(<environment>, <environment>, <environment>, 
        <environment>), scales = <environment>, mapping = structure(list(
        x = ~event.time, y = ~estimate, colour = ~gender), class = "uneval"), 
    theme = list(), coordinates = <environment>, facet = <environment>, 
    plot_env = <environment>, labels = list(title = "Austria", 
        subtitle = "Male: -9.39 Female: -1.15", x = "event.time", 
        y = "estimate", colour = "gender", fill = "gender", 
        ymin = "conf.low", ymax = "conf.high", width = "width", 
        yintercept = "yintercept")), class = c("gg", "ggplot"
 )), "Austria")
```

I am creating the next table using kable:

````
```{r austria_tab1,echo=FALSE}

 pais1<-tablas_pais(1)


kable(pais1[[1]],format="latex",caption="Overall ATT based on event study aggregation  
Austria",booktabs=TRUE,digits = 2) |>
kable_styling(position = "center",latex_options = "HOLD_position")

 ```
````

When I compile my Rmd document I am getting the next error:

```
A new version of TeX Live has been released. If you need to install or update any LaTeX 
packages, 
you have to upgrade TinyTeX with tinytex::reinstall_tinytex(repository = "illinois").
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
            $
 l.356 ...ased on event study aggregation  Austria}

Try to find the following text in Results-report.Rmd:
...ased on event study aggregation  Austria}
```

You may need to add $ $ around a certain inline R expression `r`  in Results-report.Rmd (see
the
above hint). See https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/385 for more info.
Error: LaTeX failed to compile Results-report.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging
for
debugging tips. See Results-report.log for more info.
Ejecución interrumpida

I cant understand why I should add $$..... ??

What is the problem with this?